# an Error parameter imagefilter() function in php

Tags: php

I have a file content.php with this form :

```html
            <form action="upload.php"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <label for="img">choose Your photo </label>
                <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
            </form>
```

I want the selected photo to be sent to the upload.php and there to be a negative photo with the imagefilter () function !

Upload.php :

```js
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$fileDir = $_POST['img'];
imagefilter("$fileDir",IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
?>
```

when click to submit button in content.php , show this problem : Warning: imagefilter() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp64\www\farshad\upload.php on line 8

**whats the problems ?**

Comment: `imagefilter` does _not_ want a file name as first parameter. Go read the manual for the function, it has examples.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

- upload the file to a certain location
- get that location path to the image with the file name and store in a variable
- use function `imagecreatefrompng()`. [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)
- use a function according to the type of the image. There are other funcions like `imagecreatefrompng()`
- pass this image resouce to the `imagefilter()` [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php)

eg:

```
// do file upload
// say the filename is 'flower.png'
// stored at a some location say 'path/to/flower.png'

$path = 'path/to/flower.png'

$img = imagecreatefrompng($path)

imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
```

Read the docs. This is for png images. There are other functions too. Explore more.

Comment: Hey bro , $path is just for flower.png !! i want the selected picture in content.php return to upload.php and use that picture for imagefilter() function !!

Comment: this is just an example. read the comments in the code. You should have the `$path` value equal to the path in which you have stored your image file.